# Moving an element to a definite position in intervals using delay

Tags: java, android, delay

I am currently doing a demo project on Android Studio, where I am supposed to move an ImageButton 25 units to the left along X-axis once a button is pressed. I am supposed to do so not instantly, but in intervals, by moving the ImageButton 5 times, 5 units in each instance. After every instance of moving the ImageButton 5 units, there should be a delay of 1000ms. I performed this task in a FOR loop, and for the delay, I used Thread.sleep(). However, INSTEAD of actually moving the ImageButton 5 units and pausing for 1000ms, it at first pauses for an entire 5000ms., and THEN moves the ImageButton 25 units instead of 5 units. How can I resolve this problem and achieve the required objective?

Note:- Here, 'player' is the ImageButton.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            currentX = player.getX();
            currentY = player.getY();
            for(int i=1 ; i<=5; i++){
                currentX -= 5;
                player.setX(currentX);
                player.setY(currentY);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Thread.sleep()`, it will block the UI for the whole time and only when `Thread.sleep()` is over, you will see the changes on the UI. Better solution is to use a `[Handler][1]`, which is used to post messages asynchronously so that the UI is not blocked.

Please try this solution and let know if it works.

```
  private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      super.handleMessage(msg);
      int currentX = msg.arg1;
      int currentY = msg.arg2;
      player.setX(currentX);
      player.setY(currentY);
    }
  }

  int count = 0;

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    int currentX = player.getX();
    int currentY = player.getY();
    MyHandler myHandler = new MyHandler();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      currentX = currentX - 5;
      currentY = currentY - 5;

      Message message = new Message();
      message.arg1 = currentX;
      message.arg2 = currentY;
      myHandler.sendMessageDelayed(message, i * 1000);

    }
  }
```